# How to import the properties of the object to user-control using C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls

I have a user control and i want to assign the properties of an object to the user control.
For example:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo();
ci.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
```

I must be able to access the method `GetAllDateTimePatterns()` using my usercontrol.
Can anybody please help me with C# coding?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Given any object, e.g. `ci.DateTimeFormat` you want to iterate all its method, execute them, and assign the return value to private fields of the user control?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the issue - if you have the code you posted above in your user control, you already have access to the `GetAllDateTimePatterns()` method.